# Place a div beneath another element

Tags: html, css, wordpress, position

I'm trying to position a div beneath another div on this page: http://www.tbbadenver.org/services/

If you take a look you can see my div at the bottom, but it overlaps one of the pictures on the bottom as well. I just need to place the div with a header and a list beneath the images. I'm using a Wordpress template and I think that might be getting in the way...

The div id is #nonPaid.
My current css is:

```
#nonPaid {
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
position: absolute;
display: inline;
bottom: 0;
clear: both;
}
```

I'm sure there are things in there that I don't need, but can anybody tell me what I'm missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Play around with the following styles for your div:

position: relative
z-index: 0

(-1 will put you underneath the container)

Also do the same for your image & border, increasing the z-index instead.

(original):
try:

```
#nonPaid {
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
position: absolute;
display: inline;
bottom: 0;
clear: both;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: I've been playing around in console, Jshields. You're right, the template is getting in the way even after you adjust z-index. We're getting under the image with z-index:0 (just tried it), but the border around the image is still on top. Try humble.rumble's idea on both the border and the image?

Comment: Hm the entire element I want my div under is .et_pt_portfolio_gallery. Changing the z-index of .et_pt_portfolio_gallery to 1 and the z-index of #nonPaid to 2 makes #nonPaid appear over .et_pt_portfolio_gallery. I'm trying to get #nonPaid under. Any more ideas? (I appreciate the help guys!)